# Question on variables in /etc/inputrc

Tags: bash, readline

In my `/etc/inputrc` file I have several `set` statements as noted below. Do all those variables belong to Readline ? How do I see the currently set values for those variables ? For bash variables I can use `$<variable>` notation to view the variable data.

```
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on

set mark-symlinked-directories on

$if mode=emacs
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they all belong to `readline`. The command `bind -V` (or `bind -v`) will give you the current values of those variables.

Comment: Thanks xhienne! I verified `bind -V` gets me the values of these variables. I though bash will have to set some local variables and then pass them to the functions of Readline library. Where can I read more about bash and readline integration ? Is that different from bash calling other programs like echo, cat etc. ?

Comment: @RaviKumar All I know about readline and bash, I got it from the bash manpage. readline is integrated in bash, as a library, you don't call it like echo, cat, etc.